# Can I compile mingw programs using the mingw folder in msvs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, mingw

So I was trying to compile Nethack but I don't want to install minGW through Sourceforge because I am not sure if it is safe because There seems to be contradictory information on whether it is safe or not.I came across this folder in msvs 2017 15.5.1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32" can I use this in place of "C:\mingw"? in a batch file the file in which I want to use it in contains the code

`PATH=c:\mingw\bin
cd src
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc install`

I just don't want to do anything wrong and mess up my computer.

Comment: If you're on Windows10, you might consider using Windows 10's "Windows Linux Subsystem" to get a reasonably sane GCC build environment.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I am using a windows 7 64-bit computer. Does this mean that my idea wouldn't work? @lockcmpxchg8b

Comment: You can certainly open the MSVC "developer console" and see if `make`, `mingw32-make`, or `mingw64-make` does anything.

Comment: Once I open the console how do I do that? @lockcmpxchg8b

Comment: I got it to work I just had to use the cd command in the dev console to get to the src directory and run the command nmake install.